# PHP's preg_replace regex that matches multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

How do I create a regex that takes into account that the subject consists of multiple lines?

The "`m`" modifier for one does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you positive the regex is correct?

Comment: use msU
for detail read a link below http://zendf.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/php-preg_match-multi-line-match/

Answer (score 49):

Maxwell Troy Milton King is right, but since his answer is a bit short, I'll post this as well and provide some examples to illustrate.

First, the `.` meta character by default does NOT match line breaks. This is true for many regex implementations, including PHP's flavour. That said, take the text:

```
$text = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
```

and the regex

```
'/.*/'
```

then the regex will only match `Line 1`. See for yourself:

```
preg_match('/.*/', $text, $match);
echo $match[0]; // echos: 'Line 1'
```

since the `.*` "stops matching" at the `\n` (new line char). If you want to let it match line breaks as well, append the s-modifier (aka DOT-ALL modifier) at the end of your regex:

```
preg_match('/.*/s', $text, $match);
echo $match[0]; // echos: 'Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3'
```

Now about the m-modifier (multi-line): that will let the `^` match not only the start of the input string, but also the start of each line. The same with `$`: it will let the `$` match not only the end of the input string, but also the end of each line.

An example:

```
$text = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]$/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

which will match only the 3 (at the end of the input). But:

but enabling the m-modifier:

```
$text = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]$/m', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

all (single) digits at the end of each line ('1', '2' and '3') are matched.

Answer (score 8):

Try the 's' modifier. Meaning 'treat as if a single line'.

'm' enables the use of ^ and $ line beginnings and endings to be used.

Comment: Ah IC, will try that @work tomorrow. One more question though, how do I match newlines, spaces or tabs? So far I've come up with "[ \\n\\t]*", that is correct?

Comment: Just use `\s`, which means any space character.

Comment: \s matches 'white space' (meaning \t and space) and I believe it may include \n as well when used with 's'.

Comment: @Maxwell, no, in nearly all regex flavours, `\s` matches at least these four chars `[ \t\r\n]` (space, tab, carriage return, new line).

Comment: Even when it's not 'single-line'?

Comment: Yes, `\s` is not affected by any of the modifiers. It will always match the same.