# php remove whitespace between 2 tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove signature of an email before inserting the message into a database. The signature is enclosed in a special tag, xxx to help strip out.

The following only works if the signature is condensed without whitespace spread over various lines.

```
    $msgeBody = preg_replace('#(<signature>).*?(</signature>)#', '$1$2', $msgeBody);
```

I have tried possibilities found online to remove whitespace first between these tags, before applying the line above. But no success. How to do? Here is the sample text spread over lines:-

```
    <signature><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">Gerald Sugan</span><br>
    Travel Consultant<br>
    <span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Courier New'; font-weight: bold;">Sugan Enterprises Inc</span></p>
    </signature>
```

The solution of [php preg_replace regex that matches multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240348/php-preg-replace-regex-that-matches-multiple-lines) is not a duplicate. I could not see how to apply those solutions here. The solution found below is different I think.

Comment: Don't use `.+?` use `[\S\s]+?` which will search for both non-whitespace and whitespace characters. see here https://regex101.com/r/wS0vX9/1

Comment: re Kenney, not sure how to adapt that link as first time using preg. Tried these without success: $msgeBody = preg_replace('#(<signature>)/.*/(</signature>)#', '$1$2', $msgeBody);
$msgeBody = preg_replace('#(<signature>)/[0-9]$/m(</signature>)#', '$1$2', $msgeBody);

Comment: Re Terminus, great that worked! I am left with the signature tags and nothing inside, but can remove those easily. Thanks for creating the example. Do you want to copy the solution into a separate answer so I can tick correct?

Comment: @Paul It's correctly marked as duplicate. In the accepted answer, it says: "*If you want to let it match line breaks as well, append the s-modifier*". That means that, after the `#` delimiter, you need to add an `s`. i.e: `'#<signature>.*?</signature>#s'`, which is slightly more efficient and easier to read than `[\s\S]`... That said, I'd still go with [DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33838227/5290909)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple regex that match your signature : `<signature>[\S\s]*<\/signature>`

**\S** : Matches anything other than a space, tab or newline.
**\s** : Matches any space, tab or newline character.
* : Matches zero or more consecutive characters.

Comment: Yes, this works. It was suggested first by Terminus above so am waiting to see if he enters this as solution before ticking.

Comment: @Paul I won't be. Go ahead. Though do check out Casimir's answer. It's pretty slick

Comment: This is performing a greedy match and it could fail with multiple `<signature>` tags, even though it wasn't clear in the question if there might be more than one.

Comment: @Mariano I agree with you

Comment: Using `explode()` would get the earliest one `$msgeBody[0]` and enable you to dump anything after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$mail= <<<'EOD'
<body>
blah blah blah
<signature><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">Gerald Sugan</span><br>
    Travel Consultant<br>
 <span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Courier New'; font-weight: bold;">Sugan Enterprises Inc</span></p>
    </signature>
blah blah blah
</body>
EOD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($mail, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('signature') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Trim() /*Function that remove the whitespaces or a caracter which you specified*/:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Comment: Tried this, no effect. Put $msgeBody = trim($msgeBody);
But this just removes whitespace before/after I think, not within the signature tags.

Comment: Hrs trying remove whitespace from inside the string not on the edges. Look at his example.

Answer (score 0):

Explode would separate the signature from the email body and is quite a short piece of code but you would need to get rid of the last left-over tag.

To answer the original query `chop($yourString, ' ' )` should remove all the whitespaces inside `$yourString`  Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php

Your email is held in a variable called `$msgeBody`so split it at "signature" and trim off the remaining tag.

```
   $msgeBody = explode("signature", $msgeBody);
   $msgeBody = rtrim($msgeBody[0], "<");
```

Clean up `$msgeBody` before putting it in your database.

Using `$msgeBody = explode("signature", $msgeBody);` leaves the first `<` from "signature" on the end of the first part - the body of the email  - which would be in array position `$msgeBody[0]`.

`str_replace('<','', $msgeBody[0]);` would also remove the tag but if you have other tags in `$msgeBody` it would remove those too.

`rtrim($msgeBody[0], "<");` should remove it better. 
`substr()` also has possibilities http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and would find the first occurrence of ''

`rtrim($msgeBody,'<signature>');` might also chop it off but with Mariano's caveat about multiple signatures. Not tested.

`strip_tags($msgeBody, '');` will get rid of all the tags in case that could be used.  (You put any tags you want to keep in the `''` -  as in '`<br />`' for example.)

Comment: This would fail in the case where the e-mail body has a literal `signature`.

Comment: @Mariano Ahh I see what you mean - sorry  -is there an option to explode on /body? Not sure that explode will accept the tags. To avoid the word in the text scenario you could check for the `<` left over and if it is not there move down the array but then you would lose the speed advantage. This worked for me for another situation well though.

Comment: I don't know. I'd use [DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33838227/5290909)