# preg_replace more lines php

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-parsing

The code:

```
$message = preg_replace("/<div style='background-color:#C0C8D0;width:95%;'>SMA Forr&aacute;sk&oacute;d: <a href='' onclick='selectcode\\((.*)\\);return false;'>\\[ Mindet kijelol \\]<\\/a><\\/div><div id='(.*)' style=\"width:95%;max-width:95%;max-height: 500px; overflow:scroll;background-color: #FFFFFF;\"><pre class=\"sma\" style=\"font-family:monospace;font-size: 12px;\"><ol><li style=\"font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em\\/1\\.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">(.*)<\\/div><\\/li><\\/ol><\\/pre><\\/div>/", '[sma]<pre>$3</pre>[/sma]',$message);
```

Its work, only if the post is have only one line. I want to use multiple lines:

Example:
Now i edit this post

```
->

[sma]Now i edit this post[/sma]
```

Its good, and i have more lines:
Example:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

this output:

```
[sma]line1line2line3line4line5line6[/sma]
```

and i want:

```
[sma]line1

line2

line3

line4

line5

line6
[/sma]
```

The multiple lines html output:

```
<div style='background-color:#C0C8D0;width:95%;'>SMA Forr&aacute;sk&oacute;d: <a href='' onclick='selectcode(93347);return false;'>[ Mindet kijelol ]</a></div><div id='93347' style="width:95%;max-width:95%;max-height: 500px; overflow:scroll;background-color: #FFFFFF;"><pre class="sma" style="font-family:monospace;font-size: 12px;"><ol><li style="font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;"><div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">line1</div></li><li style="font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;"><div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">line2</div></li><li style="font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;"><div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">line3</div></li><li style="font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;"><div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">line4</div></li><li style="font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;"><div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">line5</div></li><li style="font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;"><div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">line6</div></li></ol></pre></div>
```

Comment: this one is way out of context... Explain your requirements well

Comment: You need to use the `s` modifier so the `.` extends to newlines. Your "multiple lines html" are all on one line here so maybe that isn't the issue? You're more than likely better off using a parser.

Comment: You might want to try this link from another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240348/php-preg-replace-regex-that-matches-multiple-lines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Use an HTML parser.  The problem you are having is the #1 reason that processing HTML with regexes is a road to frustration.

Comment: Okey, i need example.

Comment: There are numerous parsers and examples on the linked thread. If you have a specific issue with a parser please update your question with the code and the issue.

Comment: But I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are either trying to learn `regex` parsing in `PHP` or you are trying to parse `HTML` to make something out of it. I did it once to make an `XML generator` named [hFeeds](https://github.com/shafihuzaib/hfeeds) (Check the Development Branch for my latest commits). You should have a look at its code, in case you are trying to achieve the same. [Note: I stopped working on it a long time ago, because I developed another better one using Laravel framework and currently empowering my website [MonitorKashmir.com](http://www.monitorkashmir.com) namely `haaput`.

As the comments above suggested, parsing `HTML` using `regular expressions` is hardly recommended. In most of the cases, you should use [HTML/XML Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php), as suggested above, e.g; `SimpleXML` provided within `PHP`.

Some suggestions:

1. [Study](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp) about `SimpleXML` and its usage.
2. Use [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to check out `regular expressions` and its **Code Generator** to `generate PHP code` (at-least for time-being)

Anyways for the problem above, if we analyse, we need a pattern that repeats itself. In this case, it is:

```
<div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">[CONTENT TO BE CAPTURED]</div>
```

So we only need to capture the `[CONTENT TO BE CAPTURED]` part and we should be fine. As per all the information provided here-in, I assume that the `[CONTENT TO BE CAPTURED]` is only alpha-numeric, that is, it contains only Letters & digits until next `</div>` is encountered.

So the solution for the problem will be the following {`$str` can contain content from some `url`, e.g;

```
$str = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/example.html");
```

And it can be replaced in the following code accordingly }.

```
$re = "/<div style=\"font: normal normal 1em\\/1\\.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">([[:alnum:]]*)<\\/div>/"; 
$str = "<div style='background-color:#C0C8D0;width:95%;'>SMA Forr&aacute;sk&oacute;d: <a href='' onclick='selectcode(93347);return false;'>[ Mindet kijelol ]</a></div><div id='93347' style=\"width:95%;max-width:95%;max-height: 500px; overflow:scroll;background-color: #FFFFFF;\"><pre class=\"sma\" style=\"font-family:monospace;font-size: 12px;\"><ol><li style=\"font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">line1</div></li><li style=\"font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">line2</div></li><li style=\"font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">line3</div></li><li style=\"font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">line4</div></li><li style=\"font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">line5</div></li><li style=\"font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;\"><div style=\"font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;\">line6</div></li></ol></pre></div>\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, the str is not constans, if possible to have 65000 line.

Comment: Will it contain only alpha-numeric? or html tags as well?

Comment: As per your link, it contains only alpha-numeric.. The above should be fine. However, I am re-editing my answer above..